# Difference between worker, workman, employee

Tags: word-difference

I was reading a paragraph on the advantages of scientific management to workers and employees.

But I don't get the difference between workman, worker, employee.

Thanks in advance,......

Answer (score 0):

A **worker** is a general term for anybody of either gender who is working at something. Where companies are involved, the term is more often used of junior personnel. Workers may work for themselves or for others. But the term applies equally, if rarely, to the managing director of a company or the prime minister when s/he is pulling out weeds in the garden at home. They are working.

A **workman** is a man who is working. The term is most often used of men engaged in manual labour although **workmen** may well be craftsmen, highly skilled at what they do. Again, a workman may be self-employed or may work for others.

An **employee** is someone, whether male or female, who is employed by someone else. The term usually, but not necessarily, implies a contract of employment and generally refers to someone in full-time employment with a company. It is more often used of junior personnel than senior staff.

Comment: "Workman" is severely deprecated by many British English speakers because it is seen to carry snobbish implications.

Comment: I've no argument with Michael Harvey although I would make the distinction between describing an individual as (just) a workman and saying something like **There were workmen on the site for the first time today**, where the sense of **workers** is intended. True, there are also likely to be workwomen on site these days. And if you feel really strongly, you can imitate the British female MP who spoke of a **workpersonlike** approach.